# Passing Login Parameters to a webservice using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am working on a cordova app. I need to use the webservice with same origin policy so I used `$.ajax()` method to communicate using webservice.

I need to login so am passing HTML, user provided username and password, but also the response text giving an error saying tat i need to pass Login Parameter along with Username and Password inputs.

> responseText: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The login parameter is mandatory
>   Caused by: The login parameter is mandatory, textStatus: error, errorThrown: undefined

I have the webservice url and also Login parameter but dont know how to pass all three ie Uname, Pwd and login parameters in data: part of ajax can anyone help me regarding this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://------", // URL 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    // send username and password as parameters 
    data: "userName=" + username + "&password=" + password,
    // script call was *not* successful
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('div#loginResult').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ", textStatus: " + textStatus + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
    }, // error 
    // script call was successful 
    // data contains the JSON values returned by the Perl script 
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.error) { // script returned error
            $('div#loginResult').text("data.error: " + data.error);
            $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
        } // if
        else { // login was successful
            $('form#loginForm').hide();
            $('div#loginResult').text("data.success: " + data.success + ", data.employeeId: " + data.employeeId);
            $('div#loginResult').addClass("success");
        } //else
    } // success
}); // ajax
} // if
```

Comment: You just need to amend the `data` property to include the `login` parameter, wherever you get that value from.

Comment: try with: `data: {userName: username, password: password}`

Comment: Did you make sure that authentication service requires parameters named exatly `userName` & `password` and no other?

Comment: You can remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` option as you are sending data as parameters and not as json where you content type would be `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` which is default and you don't have to specify one.

Comment: yes am sure about parameters name

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to send a POST request and writing the data as GET parameters and that too in a wrong place.

Try the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://------", // URL 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    // send username and password as parameters 
    data: {"userName": username, "password" : password},
    // script call was *not* successful
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('div#loginResult').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ", textStatus: " + textStatus + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
    }, // error 
    // script call was successful 
    // data contains the JSON values returned by the Perl script 
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.error) { // script returned error
            $('div#loginResult').text("data.error: " + data.error);
            $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
        } // if
        else { // login was successful
            $('form#loginForm').hide();
            $('div#loginResult').text("data.success: " + data.success + ", data.employeeId: " + data.employeeId);
            $('div#loginResult').addClass("success");
        } //else
    } // success
}); // ajax
} // if
```

Only change I made is with the "data" key here

Comment: Or just remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` option and previous code should work just same.

Comment: @sameer are you sure, sending the parameters as param1=somevalue&param2=somevalue should be accessible by the server side code as $_POST['param1'] and $_POST['param2'] then ?

Comment: yes it will be as `Jquery Ajax` default `ContentType` is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`. Now @Tech Cruize has declared `ContentType` as json where data is parameterized. .

Comment: Yes that's a valid point, the only thing I am concerned about his server side code to get the request parameters.

Comment: Request will send both `'userName'` and `'password'` key-value parameter inside PUT request body, so `$_POST['userName']` && `$_POST['password']` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks evryone for your precious reply, @sameer i have edited the data part, but what exactly my concern is that i need to send a Json parameter to webservice to get response. eg: "loginemployee" is the Json parameter i need to send along with uname & pwd, how do i do that.

Comment: @Tech you can make use of JSON.stringify method of JS to send out the JSON encoded data instead of doing the way you are doing right now.

Comment: Hi zafar, may i know the syntax of JSON.stringify through any of the code snippets.